# Visual Studio Extensions - support multiple versions of VS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vspackage

I've been writing an extension (Editor Classifier project, with some other features chipped in. It works fine on VS2013, but I need to support other versions VS2012 and VS2015(when it is out of Preview).

When I just add supported versions in the `vsixmanifest`, the problem that I'm facing is, the export of `ITestContainerDiscoverer` or `IClassificationTypeRegistryService` fails complaining

`ContractName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Classification.IClassificationTypeRegistryService")' is not assignable to type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Classification.IClassificationTypeRegistryService'`

My guess is that this is because I am referencing invalid SDK versions. I could always write different versions, but is there a way to share an extension across versions of visual studio?

Comment: Have you tried to Reference the lowest version...

Comment: See if this helps: How to create a Visual Studio extensibility project that is compatible with VS 2010, 2012 and 2013
http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/kzu/how-to-create-a-visual-studio-extensibility-project-that-is-compatible-with-vs-2010-2012-and-2013/

Comment: @ErikEJ - thanks for the tip, it seems to work except for my `TestAdapters`. Need to dig in a bit more. @Carlos - that blog focuses more on upgrading a project seamlessly across versions, while I need to generate binaries that works across versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ErikEJ's tip worked for me. I had to port the extension project to VS2012 and build it with `target` set to `[11.0,12.0]` and this ensured that the VSIX that I generated worked for both VS2012 and VS2013. No errors too!